# Check Entered Value against XML Document

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm trying to check if the entered key matches the key held by a user. I figured XML would be the easiest however I have no experience in working with XML documents. Could someone please help me understand how to search the XML document like this pseudo code below in visual basic?

> Entered name = Tim AND Entered Key = 4545 THEN Return true as value is correct for Tim.
>
> Entered name = Sharon AND Entered Key = 1010 THEN Return false as
>   value is wrong for Sharon.
>
> Entered name = Tim AND Entered key = 6565 return false as this is
>    Sharon's key.

Basically just checking the two values entered match up with the correct details. I usually do this through a database but circumstances mean this must be done offline.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="RegistrationTable.xsd" generated="2016-11-06T14:49:10">
<RegistrationTable>
    <ID>1</ID>
        <First_Name>Tim</First_Name>
        <Last_Name>Far</Last_Name>
        <Key>4545</Key>
        <Expire>2016-11-06T00:00:00</Expire>
    <ID>2</ID>
        <First_Name>Sharon</First_Name>
        <Last_Name>Far</Last_Name>
        <Key>6565</Key>
        <Expire>2016-11-06T00:00:00</Expire>
</RegistrationTable>
</dataroot>
```

Comment: How was the XML created?  It looks like you are using it as a database of sorts in which case loading it to a DataTable would make it easy to iterate or query

Comment: As I'm inexperienced with XML I exported a database into an XML document to get me start.

Comment: So load it back to a DataTable and use that.  It makes the whole XML thing an implementation detail

Comment: That XML appears to be poorly formed. The <First_Name>, <Last_Name> etc. should be child elements of <ID>.